# Cordova plugin me.apla.cordova.app-preferences - success callback not fired some times

Tags: android, cordova, plugins

This is regarding the usage of Cordova plugin "me.apla.cordova.app-preferences", which is used for saving to and retrieving from application preferences (SharedPreferences in Android and NSUserDefaults in iOS). While trying to fetch a previously saved value, some times success callback or failure callback is not being fired for both iOS and Android. But sometimes it fires successfully. Its a strange behavior. Here is the snippet of the JS code that I've used for retrieving value using the plugin:

```
var prefs = window.plugins.appPreferences; prefs.fetch(prefReadSucess, prefReadFailed, 'key');


function prefReadSucess(value) {
    // handle success call back
}

function prefReadFailed(error) {
    // handle failure callback
}
```

The jave code for the plugin is,

```
private boolean fetchValueByKey(final String key, final CallbackContext callbackContext) {
    cordova.getThreadPool().execute(new Runnable() {public void run() {

    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(cordova.getActivity());
    String returnVal = null;
    if (sharedPrefs.contains(key)) {
        Object obj = sharedPrefs.getAll().get(key);
        String objClass = obj.getClass().getName();
        if (objClass.equals("java.lang.Integer")) {
            returnVal = obj.toString();
        } else if (objClass.equals("java.lang.Float") || objClass.equals("java.lang.Double")) {
            returnVal = obj.toString();
        } else if (objClass.equals("java.lang.Boolean")) {
            returnVal = (Boolean)obj ? "true" : "false";
        } else if (objClass.equals("java.lang.String")) {
            if (sharedPrefs.contains("_" + key + "_type")) {
                // here we have json encoded string
                returnVal = (String)obj;
            } else {
                String fakeArray = null;
                try {
                    fakeArray = new JSONStringer().array().value((String)obj).endArray().toString();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    callbackContext.error(0);
                    return;
                }
                returnVal = fakeArray.substring(1, fakeArray.length()-1);
                // returnVal = new JSONStringer().value((String)obj).toString();
            }

        } else {
            Log.d("", "unhandled type: " + objClass);
        }
        // JSONObject jsonValue = new JSONObject((Map) obj);
        callbackContext.success(returnVal);
    } else {
    }

    }});

    return true;
}
```

It is working properly when I comment the line from the java code,

**cordova.getThreadPool().execute(new Runnable() {public void run() {**

I tried to print the value of **returnVal** just before the line,

**callbackContext.success(returnVal);**

I am getting the values always. But some time the success call back is not firing,
I've ensured that the plugin is being accessed on or after the 'device ready' event. Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you got some solution for this even I am having the same issue?